# Screen resizing stuck for question with a lot of answers

Tags: bug, ios-app

Open question with many of answers, e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/339911). Scroll down several times to force loading of the rest of answers. Rotate your iDevice (tested on iPad) quickly. Screen resizing stuck after stoping rotation.

> [image: vertical]

> [image: horizontal]

Rest of UI is working well: can scroll, select tabs etc. Looks like screen size is locked with one dimension from portrait mode and another one from landscape mode.

Dropping app to background and restore - fixes dimensions.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)